# Not able to type Hangul letters

Tags: language-support, ibus, input-method, korean

I would like to occasionally type some hangul letters by pressing SUPER+SPACE and select "Korean" input. But I am not able to make it work yet on Ubuntu 22.04. When I press SUPER+SPACE I can choose between korean and norwegian:

[image]

if I choose "ko" (korean) and start typing in e.g. gedit I only get american characters. How can I get the hangul letters?

The "Keyboard" settings page shows the following:

[image]

The "Region & Language" settings show:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit**:

I discovered another settings dialog only available through the shell command "ibus-setup":

[image]

Here, I added "Korean-Hangul" from the "Input Method" tab:

[image]

Clicking the "Preferences" button in the dialog gives me a new "IBusHangul Setup" dialog:

[image]

Here, I added a new toggle key "CTRL+SPACE" and also checked the box "Start in Hangul mode". After applying these changes and logging out and in again, still it does not work.

Comment: I don't type in Korean, but I do sometimes type in Japanese.  When I switch over from English to Japanese, I have to click the IME in the top menu and then select "Input Sources", and then select Japanese.  Not sure if this is the case with Korean as well...  (It is a bit annoying to have to go through this extra step and I haven't yet found a solution.)

Comment: @Ray What do you mean by "IME in the top menu"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!  Seems like you've solved your problem, which is good to know!  "IME" was unfortunately a Windows term, I think.  Sorry about that.  "Input Method Editor"?  It's the icon in the top menu that says "en" and if you click it, I guess you have the option to switch to "ko".  For me, when I switch to "ja", I need to do an extra step and change the "Input Sources".  Has bugged me for ages, but I've been too lazy to look into it (other annoyances bug me even more, so I let this one slide).  Anyway, good to know you solved your problem with Gunnar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install the Hangul IBus package:

  ```
  sudo apt install ibus-hangul
  ```
- Log out and log in again
- Add **Korean (Hangul)** to your input sources (you can as well remove the pure **Korean** layout from your list)
- Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it says *"ibus-hangul is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build2)."* so I guess the package was already installed?

Comment: And there is no "Korean (Hangul)" in the input source selection dialog as far as I can see

Comment: And I have also tried logging in and out a couple of times, but nothing changes

Comment: I also discovered some additional settings only accessible through the shell command "ibus-setup", see my edited question above for more information. Even with those changes, it does not work.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Don't bother with `ibus-setup` for this on Ubuntu. But I'm sure that Korean (Hangul) is available in Settings. In your case, since the Korean locale has been generated, you find it by selecting Korean which opens a new window which includes Korean (Hangul). HTH

Comment: *"... you find it by selecting Korean ..."* Is this from the "Keyboard" settings page? If I click "Korean" there nothing happens

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes. And when saying that I assume that the `ko_KR.utf8` locale is included if you run `locale -a`. But maybe you need to relogin first...

Comment: I just rebooted my machine, so I do not think I need another relogin :).. Yes `locale -a | grep KR` gives "ko_KR.utf8". But why does nothing happen when i click "Korean"? Do you have a new window open just by clicking there?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/fntQe30 I am not able to open a new window from there

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Ah, then I understand. I mean you should click the + button, and then Korean.

Comment: Yes but there is no "Korean (Hangul)" there: https://imgur.com/a/Og7immE (scroll down to see 5 screenshots)

Comment: Ahh.. I think I found it. In the first screen shot in the previous imgur link, I should choose "Korean" (even if I already have a "Korean" input source). Then I got this new window: https://imgur.com/a/Jk6QbDd, where I could select "Korean (Hangul)" from the three options.. So now I have three input sources: https://imgur.com/a/ASs0goH. But choosing input source #3 Korean (Hangul) using SUPER+SPACE, I still only get american characters..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: When Korean (Hangul) is enabled, click the input source indicator in the top bar, select Configure, and check "Start in Hangul mode".

Comment: There is no "Configure", but there is "Setup". When I go there I come the IBus Hangul setup dialog (I have already used that dialog when I ran `ibus-setup` from the command line) and I had already checked that box "Start in Hangul mode". It does not help, it still only outputs american letters.. See: https://imgur.com/a/NRGqH39 (scroll down to see 2 screenshots)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Then (hopefully) it will start working if you reboot once again. (I suspect that is needed because of the way GNOME deals with IBus.)

Comment: Yes it works now!! After rebooting it is working finally. Thanks for fantastic support :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: It looks like my original answer was a bit too short. ;) But I don't like the need for this last reboot. I'll do some tests and reconsider a configuration detail. Anyway, glad that it works for you at last.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: FYI, the bug (i.e. the need for the last login/reboot) is now about to be fixed: https://launchpad.net/bugs/2007379